# Which MySQL INSERT method would be faster and more reliable?

Tags: java, mysql, insert, reliability

I am developing a web-based application, which processes high amount of data (200.000 - 500.000 rows) with a `Java` applet, then the data has to be inserted into `MySQL`. `Java` is a must, it cannot be ignored or replaced

Which method would be faster and more hassle-free, secure?

- Parse the data in Java, send the generated `TreeMap` to the `PHP` with `GZIP` compression, then prepare the rows in `PHP` with `$q -> bind_param($a, $b, $c);`, then `$q -> execute();`.
- Or parse the data in `Java` with `batchStatement.addBatch();`, create many `INSERT` statement, write that to `String`, compress that with `GZIP`, send it to `PHP`, then from `PHP`, execute `LOAD_FILE('xy.tar.gz');` in MySQL.

Comment: Try it. A bit of benchmarking will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Load_File is the fastest.

Read more:

http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/ 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  `batchStatement.addBatch()` will do what you expect. That's for executing a batch of queries inside JDBC, connecting directly with your DB from Java. It will not generate you the code of the SQL.

Furthermore, [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) does not do what you expect, that's for loading a full file into a string field. Perhaps you are thinking of [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) but, again, this does not expect a bunch of INSERT.

It's not clear if you want to this only once, or regularly. And why you insist on using PHP (are you connecting remotely with a web app that does the insert? are you aware of the security implications of this?).